# BASH arrays and variables of variables in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, bash, variables

Sometimes it is handy to protect long scripts in C++.

The following syntax works fine for simple commands:

```
#define SHELLSCRIPT1 "\
#/bin/bash \n\
echo \"hello\" \n\
"
int main ()
{
cout <<system(SHELLSCRIPT1);
return 0;
}
```

Link: http://www.unix.com/showthread.php?t=216190

Unfortunately for there are problems for 1d arrays:

```
array=(a1 a2 a3)
```

error message:

> sh: 12: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

and variables of variables:

```
var=VAR
k=0
VAR0=good
echo $VAR0; echo blah
eval "echo "\$$var$k""[/I]*
```

error message:

> warning: unknown escape sequence: '\$' [enabled by default]

Please excuse my ignorance ... Is there a solution? What are the limitations of the aforementioned C++. Calling a Bash script from C++ is not the optimum solution for my case. The script needs to be inside the .cpp

Thanks

Comment: This question is unclear. Please show some input that you give to system function call.

Comment: You have the clear input. Everything is clear. The solution to the variables of variables problem is the adoption of this syntax " \"$\"$var$k "  . The arrays questions stays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood how system() works. It will call the command interpreter with the given string. So std::system("echo \"Hello\"") calls the echo program with "Hello" as argument. You can call the command interpreter and suply it with a string it can evaluate as a script

```
const std::string script("bash -c 'as=(123 456)\n\
for a in ${as[@]}; do \
   echo $a;\
done'\
");

int main() {
    std::system(script.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the addition of this line to your code:  array=(\"a1\" \"a2\") \n\ causes the error message "Syntax error: "(" unexpected" . Just with the "hello" the code works. Array definition (and variables of variables) in the context of this syntax is the issue

Comment: The code compiles and runs for me even after adding `array=(\"a1\" \"a2\") \n\ ` to the SHELLSCRIPT1 string. I agree that it would help if you could post an example of code that does not work, and the error message it produces on your system.

Comment: The following WORKS:
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
#/bin/bash \n\
echo \"hello\" \n\
"
No compilation error.
Output: hello


The following does not work:

Compiler: sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;


#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
#/bin/bash \n\
array=(\"a1\" \"a2\") \n\
echo ${array[0]} \n\
"


int main()
{
        cout <<system(SHELLSCRIPT);
        return 0;
}

Comment: of course  the call is included in the first case too (the trivial echo that works
{
        cout <<system(SHELLSCRIPT);
        return 0;
}

Comment: in the array array=(\"a1\" \"a2\") the second parenthesis has a color that shows that something is wrong

Comment: This: const std::string script("echo \
'#!/bin/bash \n\
as=(123 456)\n\
for a in ${as[@]}; do \n\
   echo $a \n\
done\n\
' > tmp.txt; \n\
bash tmp.txt \
 ");

int main() {
    std::system(script.c_str());

    return 0;
}    Is not useful unless we can protect the tmp.txt. We could call a script.sh in the first place but we do not want the user to see the code

Comment: I get the same error message for the simpler syntax: cout <<system("array=(\"a1\" \"a2\"); echo ${array[1]}");